# Weird problems with pg_query_stats on v11 for the pg_hero gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to enable query stats in my server for use with the pg_hero Rails gem. I do the following:

First I set up the collector in postgresql.conf hoping it will auto load:

```
track_activities = on
track_counts = on
track_io_timing = off
track_functions = none
track_activity_query_size = 1024
stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'
```

The extension does not load automatically, maybe that configuration doesn't do anything. So anyway, then I do:

```
# create the extension
# CREATE extension pg_stat_statements;
postgres                 | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_pg_stats.sh
postgres                 | CREATE EXTENSION
```

which seems to work, no errors. Then I try to grant the privileges to an user:

```
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:05:27.533 UTC [154] STATEMENT:  GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_stat_statements_reset() TO ro;
postgres                 | ERROR:  function pg_stat_statements_reset() does not exist
postgres                 |   Granting read only privileges on 'entertastic_test' to ro
```

Not sure how the function does not exist when I just created the extension? Anyway, the server then crashes:

```
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.206 UTC [31] LOG:  could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No such file or directory
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.259 UTC [1] LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.259 UTC [1] LOG:  performing immediate shutdown because data directory lock file is invalid
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.259 UTC [1] LOG:  received immediate shutdown request
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.259 UTC [1] LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.261 UTC [31] LOG:  could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat/global.tmp": No such file or directory
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.262 UTC [30] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.262 UTC [30] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.262 UTC [30] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.268 UTC [1] LOG:  could not write pg_stat_statement file "pg_stat/pg_stat_statements.stat.tmp": No such file or directory
postgres                 | 2020-05-01 14:18:21.286 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

It has all privileges on the data dir so not sure why it won't create/access the file.

Does this stuff even work? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server is crashing because it can't find your stats temp directory. You have it set with this parameter:

```
stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'
```

And that will be relative to your `PGDATA` directory.

Please, check if that directory exists.

Comment: Yes sir the directory exists and is writable.